# sql строки для которых нет соответствия связей в другой

Tags: sql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чет у меня поехала описание поэтому прикрепил скрином

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: Либо `WHERE product NOT IN (SELECT product_id ...)`